# Display text in a specified rectangle with directwrite

Tags: directwrite

I want to display text with directwrite in a specified rectangle and with a specified font size, the text outside the rect should be cutted off.

By searching I found something about CreateTextLayout but it looked like it isn't possible to define the font size with it.

[image: Only the text in the red rectangle should be displayed]

*Thanks for answers.*

Comment: Ypu can more explain ? Thanks

Comment: I just added a picture of the problem, do ya need the code for the text format and the drawText method, too? thanks for your effort to help

Comment: if it sees fit and is necessary for a better compression of the code if it did not. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not something DirectWrite is responsible for, unless you're using `IDWriteBitmapRenderTarget`. If you're using DrawText/DrawTextLayout from Direct2D you simply need to use `D2D1_DRAW_TEXT_OPTIONS_CLIP` option. If you are using DirectWrite bitmap target, it's enough to set target size to layout size, or to blit layout size portion to your destination context.

Comment: I was trying for cutting the text to a certain rectangle so that for example only half of a 'm' appears. Sorry for the imprecision of my question.

Comment: Then I don't understand what exactly are trying to achieve. Clipping option does not care if half of line will be visible. Do you want to show only first 3 lines for given width?

Answer (score 0):

There is  [`IDWriteTextFormat::SetTrimming()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nf-dwrite-idwritetextformat-settrimming). When applied (with `SetTrimming(&DWRITE_TRIMMING{DWRITE_TRIMMING_GRANULARITY_CHARACTER,0,0}, nullptr);`), overflowing characters [glyph clusters?] and lines are omitted.